# Empty $this->data in afterDelete callback?

Tags: cakephp, models

I want to delete the associated file of a record after deleting the record.
But I get $this->data empty in after delete callback method.

Answer (score 2):

you have to store the file name in variable before delete operation.

Answer (score 1):

I agree, but the docs are little bit unclear:

```
// perhaps after deleting a record from the database, you also want to delete
// an associated file
public function afterDelete() {
    $file = new File($this->data['SomeModel']['file_path']);
    $file->delete();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is actually not empty. It's just a mistake in the docs I think. Try this:

```
// perhaps after deleting a record from the database, you also want to delete
// an associated file
public function afterDelete() {
    $file = new File($this->info['SomeModel']['file_path']);
    $file->delete();
}
```